# If VS Code is not typing | cannot type in VS CODE

Tags: visual-studio-code, vssettings

IF you cannot type in VS Code, there is something like an insert button and won't allow you to type anything, solution here:

Uninstall Vim plug-in in VS Code and the cursor will come back again.

Comment: If you want to share your knowledge, you need to write two posts: a question (written as if you don't know the answer), and an answer below it (written as if you were answering other person's question).

Answer (score 1):

IF you cannot type in VS Code, there is something like an insert button and won't allow you to type anything, solution here:

Uninstall Vim plug-in in VS Code and the cursor will come back again.